# Java Spring - Annotation configuration class

Tags: java, spring, annotations, config

I am new to Java Spring, trying to get my head around annotations.

I have various config files for various beans-i want to pull these together into a single config file - appConfig.java and then pass this file onto the ApplicationContext as an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext object

How can I do this?

Comment: what are the config files you have so far? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Hi, managed to resolve this thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use @Configuration annotation. this way:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean 
    public SpringBean getBean(){
       return new SpringBean();
    }
}
```